# How do I write an sql statement with both update and with keywords?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query which works perfectly and displays the results

```
WITH tbl1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
       tbl2.[PERSON_NAME] AS tbl2_name, * 
    FROM [tableToUpdate] tbl2
)
SELECT 
    tbl1.[PERSON_NAME], tbl3.[name]
FROM 
    tbl1
LEFT JOIN 
    [tableFirstJoin] tbl3 ON tbl3.[name] = tbl2_name
INNER JOIN 
    [tableSecondJoin] tbl4 ON tbl4.[matchColumn] = tbl3.[matchColumn]
WHERE 
    tbl1.[PERSON_NAME] is not null
```

But I now want to add an update statement to it similar to this

```
UPDATE [tableToUpdate] 
SET [column1] = tbl4.[column1], [column2] = tbl4.[column2]
FROM [tableToUpdate] tbl5
```

So I want to update columns in the same table inside the with statement, but with values from outside.

Does anyone know how I can write the query to do this update?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm just not sure where the update statement fits in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update via a cte, the syntax is:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT field FROM tbl)
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.field = t2.field
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN othertable t2 ON t1.field = t2.otherfield
```